# Spring data and oracle slow data load

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing an Spring-boot app with spring-data and oracle database. I have a couple of pretty simple tables but load of the data is so slow.

For example, loading 2000 rows from table that only have 3 columns (texts) lasts almost 25 seconds. I was using the spring data before but not with spring boot and it was not that slow. I have only one resource file application.properties and here it is.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1521:abcd
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = ____
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.maxActive=15
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=false
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.testOnReturn=true

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

I've been trying with default repository implementation like findAll() as well as with custom @Query and it is the same.

Do I need some additional configuration? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration properties, you should use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`